# ASP.NET Possible to feed a single content placeholder from multiple places?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, contentplaceholder

Is it possible to feed a single Master Page Content Placeholder from multiple areas in the child page?  Something like a string builder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use a string builder and then output that string in a single content placeholder.

You cant reference the content placeholder twice so concatenating a string is pretty much your only option.

Comment: If you have user controls (or partial views), can they access the parent form's string to build on it?

Comment: For example, can you do a (Panel) Master.FindControl("name").somethingThatAddsContent("content")?